# Wordpress, wp_handle_uploads, unique_filename_callback works differently on PROD and DEV, why?

Tags: wordpress

here is the code:

```
$result = wp_handle_upload( 'test', array(
    'test_form' => false,
    'unique_filename_callback' => function ( string $dir, string $name, string $ext): string {
        return 'original_TEMP';
    }
) );
```

this returns with this on DEV, correctly:

```
array(3) {
  ["file"]=>
  string(80) "/var/www/*****original_.jpgTEMP"
  ["url"]=>
  string(62) "https://*****original_.jpgTEMP"
  ["type"]=>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
}
```

but the extension gets in the way on PROD:

```
array(3) {
  ["file"]=>
  string(80) "/var/www/*****original_TEMP.jpg"
  ["url"]=>
  string(62) "https://*****original_TEMP.jpg"
  ["type"]=>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
}
```

Somehow the word TEMP just wont be appended to the end. Why???